# Document templates / content - how to store?

Tags: asp.net, database-design, azure, azure-web-roles

If possible - I want to use ASP.NET / Azure / Local SQL Server for caching

Is should be possible to create forms (its ok if the developer team can do that) without lots of coding work since customers will have different forms (avoid proudct lines). The forms are very basic (textboxes for strings / numeric values, radio / checkboxes / comboboxes, retreive some data from and display them). Complexer parts are packed into components / controls

- Is there a simple way to achieve that?
- Where and how to store that information? Document Store? RDBMS? (This is my most important question)

Comment: Yes it sure is possible to use ASP.NET Web Role on Azure connected to Local SQL Server but **It is a BAD Idea** due to performance and firewall configuration overhead. Also for $9.99 per month you can get 1GB SQL Azure RDBMS on cloud which will be faster and a much better alternative than using on-premise SQL Server.  Your rest of the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to keep your data and the code that accesses that data in the same place for performance reasons, so if you're going to run you ASP.NET web site in the cloud then I suggest you also put your data in the cloud.

You have three basic choices for safe, persistent storage of data in Windows Azure:

1. SQL Azure Database. Very similar to SQL Server with the same programming model.
2. Windows Azure Blob Storage. Blobs are similar to files; anything you would naturally store in a file is a good for Blob storage.
3. Windows Azure Table Storage. Low-cost data tables but without relational database features.

You can find out more about each of these storage options at Azure.com in the Developer section.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not sure how to design the software architecture of my project. How can i store those forms? Is there a best practice? The simplest way would be to store the tuple (label, value, formid) - but then the table will explode. Document storage would be great - but is it as reliable as SQL Server?